# Projection matrix still not working... [OpenGL]

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, projection, perspective

Recently I've been struggling just to set up a good perspective projection matrix and to apply it to a simple triangle. Before I show any code, I have a small question about matrix order: Do I have to multiply my view matrix with my projection matrix or multiply my projection matrix with my view matrix?

Ok now the code. I have tried many different ways to do a perspective matrix without any good result.

## 1

```
static Matrix4x4<T> Perspective_S(const T &fovy, const T &aspectRatio, const T &zNear, const T &zFar)
{
    T range = tanf(fovy / 2.0f) * zNear;

    return Matrix4x4<T>((2.0f * zNear) / (range * aspectRatio + range * aspectRatio), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, zNear / range, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.0f, -(zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear), -1.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.0f, (-(2.0f * zFar * zNear) / (zFar - zNear)), 0.0f);
}
```

## 2

```
static Matrix4x4<T> Perspective_S(const T &fovy, const T &aspectRatio, const T &zNear, const T &zFar)
{
    T f = 1.0f / tan(fovy / 2.0f);

    return Matrix4x4<T>(f / aspectRatio, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.0f, (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar), (2.0f * zFar * zNear) / (zNear - zFar),
                          0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);;
}
```

## 3

```
static Matrix4x4<T> Frustum_S(const T &left, const T &right, const T &bottom, const T &top,
                              const T &zNear, const T &zFar)
{
    return Matrix4x4<T>(2.0f * zNear / (right - left), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                       0.0f, 2.0f * zNear / (top - bottom), 0.0f, 0.0f,
                       (right + left) / (right - left), (top + bottom) / (top - bottom), -(zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear), -1.0f,
                       0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f * zFar * zNear / (zFar - zNear), 0.0f);
}
static Matrix4x4<T> Perspective_S(const T &fovy, const T &aspectRation, const T &zNear, const T &zFar)
{
    T scale = tan(fovy) * zNear;
    T r = aspectRation * scale, l = -r;
    T t = scale, b = -t;

    return Frustum_S(l, r, b, t, zNear, zFar);
}
```

## 4

```
static void Perspective_S(Matrix4x4<T> &matrix, T fovyInDegrees, T aspectRatio, T znear, T zfar)
{
    T ymax = znear * tanf(fovyInDegrees * 3.14159265358979323846 / 360.0); //c'est pas 180?
    //ymin = -ymax;
    //xmin = -ymax * aspectRatio;
    T xmax = ymax * aspectRatio;
    Frustum(matrix, -xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, znear, zfar);
}

static void Frustum_S(Matrix4x4<T> &matrix, T left, T right, T bottom, T top,
                    T znear, T zfar)
{
    T temp = 2.0f * znear;
    T temp2 = right - left;
    T temp3 = top - bottom;
    T temp4 = zfar - znear;

    matrix = Matrix4x4<T>(temp / temp2, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, temp / temp3, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          (right + left) / temp2, (top + bottom) / temp3, (-zfar - znear) / temp4, -1.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.0f, (-temp * zfar) / temp4, 0.0f);
}
```

Some of the functions look like the transposed resulting matrix of some of my other trys. All of those functions were taken from tutorials. One even came from my previous post and it's still not working...

Just in case you might think it's my LookAt code, here it is:

What I do in main.cpp

```
matptr = (Matrix4x4f::LookAt_S(eye, center, up) *
    Matrix4x4f::Perspective_S(M_PI / 3.0f, (float)window->getSize().x / (float)window->getSize().y, 0.001f, 1000.0f)).ToArray();

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "myMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &matptr[0]);
```

My LookAt code:

```
static Matrix4x4<T> LookAt_S(Vector3<T> &eye, Vector3<T> &center, Vector3<T> &up)
{
    Vector3<T> forward(center - eye);
    forward.Normalize();

    Vector3<T> side(forward.CrossProduct(up));
    side.Normalize();

    up = side.CrossProduct(forward);

    return Matrix4x4<T> (side.x, up.x, -forward.x, 0.0f,
                         side.y, up.y, -forward.y, 0.0f,
                         side.z, up.z, -forward.z, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: GLM can do this for you easily with glm::perspective(). Maybe you could try that?

Comment: Yeah! Go to the glm (gl math) website and download the headers. You can scrap all of your matrix and vector headers you've written and use glm::vec3, glm::mat4, etc. for everything. To answer your other question, the order is projectionMatrix * viewMatrix.

Comment: Make sure to call `glUniformMatrix4fv` AFTER you've done `glUseProgram(...)`.

Comment: I did. Now I'm checking glm, I think it will be for the best, as I'm not very good with maths. ^^

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about it (despite checking gml :-)), check out chapter 5, section 3 of [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming](http://www.mathfor3dgameprogramming.com).